# ANDROID: Delete textviews which are created dynamically

Tags: android, textview

I have added multiple `TextViews` dynamically in a layout,

```
 for(int x=4;x<result.length();x++)
        {
            JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(x);
            Log.i("Classlist",""+x);
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(student_profile.this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
            tv.startAnimation(animation);
            tv.setTag(tag);
            tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
            tv.setText(collegeData.getString("date") + "  " + collegeData.getString("day_name"));
            tv.setTextSize(17);
            this.linearLayout_top5classes.addView(tv);

        }
```

This loop adds `textViews` according to the data received by the url,Now i want to remove the textviews which were created in this loop and i cant find a proper method to do so....I only want to remove these textviews and not all the textviews

**UPDATE**

First i used

```
int prv=0;
```

then

```
String tag ="textView_"+x;
prv++;
```

in the first loop to generate multiple tags
then i removed them with

```
  for(int x=4;x<prv;x++)
        {
        View view = this.linearLayout_top5classes.findViewWithTag("textView_"+x);
        this.linearLayout_top5classes.removeView(view);
            Log.i("prv value",prv+"");
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course there is a way. Just look for child views with tag:

```
View view = this.linearLayout_top5classes.findViewWithTag(tag);
this.linearLayout_top5classes.removeView(view);
```

If you add ID's to child views, then:

```
View view = this.linearLayout_top5classes.findViewById(id);
this.linearLayout_top5classes.removeView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible try using different layout for the dynamically added textviews. and then remove views from second layout only. By using,:

```
linearLayout_top5classes.removeAllViews();
```

Comment: have you read OP ? `I only want to remove these textviews and not all the textviews`  your answer remove all views

Comment: If possible, use different layout for dynamically added textviews. @N J

Answer (score 0):

To remove particular view with `tag`

```
View view = this.linearLayout_top5classes.findViewWithTag(tag);

this.linearLayout_top5classes.removeView(view)
```

To remove view from particular position

```
this.linearLayout_top5classes.removeViewAt(position);
```

Use following logic to remove any view from layout.

```
this.linearLayout_top5classes..post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        this.linearLayout_top5classes..removeView(view);
    }
});
```